# Reproducibility of PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I want to train a model using PyTorch 1.6.0 with multiple gpus. I set all the seed and CUDA benchmarking.

```py
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

However, in two runs, the loss looks different.

[first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4KC4.png)

[second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLU7l.png)

The l_sup is the loss which uses another fixed pre-trained model to supervise the middle feature extraction layer. The l_pix is the original model loss.

The code looks like this:

```py
Class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.basic_model = BasicModel()
        load_path = ...
        self.pretrained_network = PretrainNetwork()
        self.load_network(self.pretrained_network, load_path)
        self.pretrained_network.eval()
        for p in self.pretrained_network.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = False
        self.basic_model = DataParallel(self.basic_model)
        self.pretrained_network = DataParallel(self.pretrained_network)
        
    def load_network(self, net, load_path, strict=True, param_key='params'):
        if isinstance(net, (DataParallel, DistributedDataParallel)):
            net = net.module
    
        load_net = torch.load(load_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
        if param_key is not None:
            load_net = load_net[param_key]
        for k, v in deepcopy(load_net).items():
            if k.startswith('module.'):
                load_net[k[7:]] = v
                load_net.pop(k)
        net.load_state_dict(load_net, strict=strict)
        
    def optimize_parameters(self):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        # left_feature and right_feature are the output of middle feature extraction layer, cost_volume is the final output of the model
        left_feature, right_feature, cost_volume = self.basic_model(self.left_seq,  self.right_seq)
            
        # the output of middle feature extraction layer of pre-trained model
        left_cnn_feature, right_cnn_feature = self.pretrained_network(self.left_seq, self.right_seq)

        l_total = 0
            
        # loss of original model
        l_pix = self.basic_loss(cost_volume, self.gt)
        l_total += l_pix
            
        # loss of supervision of pre-trained model
        l_sup = 0.5 * self.feature_loss(left_feature, left_cnn_feature) + 0.5 * self.feature_loss(right_feature, right_cnn_feature)
        l_total += l_sup

        l_total.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```

In order to ensure that the pre-trained model doesn't update its parameters, I load the weights of the pre-trained model and write

```py
self.pretrained_network.eval()
for p in self.pretrained_network.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False
```

The strange thing is that if I only use l_pix, which means deleting these two lines

```py
l_sup = 0.5 * self.feature_loss(left_feature, left_cnn_feature) + 0.5 * self.feature_loss(right_feature, right_cnn_feature)
l_total += l_sup
```

the reproducibility is guaranteed. I'd like to know why adding the l_sup leads to non-reproducibility?

Comment: Is the "fixed pre-trained model" in `eval` or in `train`? Although the batches aren't suppose to be different batch normalization may be the reason.

Comment: The pre-trained model shouldn't be updated, so I set the `requires_grad` to be `False`. The  network is in `eval`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly how you use pre-trained model to supervise the middle feature extraction layer?

Comment: How is `self.feature_loss` defined exactly?

Comment: It's just simple L1 loss.

Comment: And, where is `pretrained_network` being used?

Comment: Sorry, I have mistyped the code. The `pretrained_network` is being used to calculate `left_cnn_feature` and `right_cnn_feature`.